# Looking for a way to write collected in-memory-logs in an android app just before the app closes

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

For the purpose of profiling, I instrumented my android application so that it collects some log at the beginnings and ends of all functions. I do so by calling a public static method called `keepLog(String log)` at method boundaries. I also wrote another public static method called `writeCollectedLogs()` which is supposed to write all collected logs into disk. It is important that all logs are written at once because I do not want to use write system-call every time (instead I prefer to keep logs in memory and write everything on disk only once at the end)

My problem is I do not know where to call `writeCollectedLogs()`. I am looking for some `onTerminate()` method for the whole android app. However, non of android default `onDestroy` and `onTerminate()` seems to work in my case. It is important to note that I have 2 methods of running my application. Sometimes I run my app using android instrumentation test runner and sometimes I use adb to start activities and send touch events manually.

Instrumentation test runner opens my app, runs the tests and then closes the app. In the second scenario however, I have control over my app life cycle. I am looking for a universal way of calling for `writeCollectedLogs` just before the app closes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated because there is no universal answer for this problem. If you are using only Activities, **onPause()** is the only method that is always called (except application crash). Unfortunately, **onStop()** and **onDestroy()** are not called with 100% probability. However the android documentation advises to avoid CPU-intensive work in **onPause()**.